# How to sort CollectionViewSource's groups

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have following collection view

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="messages" Source="{Binding src}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Then I assign it to TreeView's ItemsSource. Now, how to sort *Groups* by their name? They appear to have random order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just sort by the group. This should work:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="messages" Source="{Binding src}"> 
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions> 
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group"/> 
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions> 
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <SortDescription PropertyName="Group" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: do you happen to know how to pull that off in code? My intention is to sort existing groups within the grid when a ascending/descending button is clicked. What is happening is that I am able to sort my rows by the fieldname, but not the groups.

Comment: TWood - messages.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Group", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

Comment: Just in case someone has the same problem as me: You might need to add xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase" in your Window definition and use `scm' as namespace for SortDescription.